# issue to generate fat jar for the subproject in subpackage

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I defined the subproject to create the fat jar for subpackage `com.mycompany.proj.util`. But the jar created (using `sbt utilProject/assembly`) only contains scala sdk classes and did not have the subpackage classes. Any ideas why? Do I need to specify the full path of the package? thanks

`lazy val utilProject = (project in file("util"))
  .enablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)
  .settings(assemblyJarName in assembly := "utilProject.jar")`

Comment: Which command did you use to create the jar?